# I'm trying to create dynamic SQL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I use MySql and I have some problems with it ^^

Let's say I have two tables which will be "FirstTable" and "SecondTable"

First table (ID isn't the primary key)

```
ID      IdCust   Ref
1       300      123
1       300      124
2       302      345
```

And the second (ID isn't the primary key)

```
ID     Ref      Code    Price
1      123      A       10
1      123      Y       15
2      124      A       14
3      345      C       18
```

[EDIT] The column "Stock" in the final result is equals to "ID" in the second table
The column "Stock", "Code" and "Price" can have x values, so I don't know it, in advance...

I make some research in stackoverflow, but I only find post where people use "count(case when ..."
Like this one : [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

For my problem, I cannot use it, because i can't know in advance the value of reference

I'm trying to produce the following output:

[The result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOkxi.png)

[EDIT] Result in TXT

```
ID IdCust Ref StockA Code1 Price1 StockB Code2 Price2
1  300    123 1      A     10     1      Y     15
1  300    124 2      A     14     
2  300    345 3      C     18
```

Comment: Please take a few moments and include your desired output directly in the question.  Also show us any query you may have tried.

Comment: You're talking about a column `Stock`, that is not in your table description.

Comment: please add a DB FIDDLE: https://dbfiddle.uk with the data you have and the query you tried

Comment: I edit my post, thank you for comment, I forget to said something about "Stock"
@TimBiegeleisen I cannot include the desired output because I have less than 10 reputations ... I can only add a link. My "solutions" (which is not good for my desired solution) use "count case when ...". If i make this post, that's because I didn't find any solutions :/

Comment: You certainly can add your output as text.  We know this is possible because you included the input.

Comment: I thought you want a picture in my first post, I added a text :)